# What is the difference between the below notations?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I've often come across two ways of integrating which I think mean the same thing.

1. $\displaystyle \int f(x) dx$
2. $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx$

Do these two mean the same thing because, both seem to integrating the function over the whole domain. If yes, then why don't we just use one of the two? And if no, then what's the difference?

Comment: The first is an **indefinite integral**.  It is not integrating over any interval.  It is an antiderivative function.

Comment: Which means that it is integrating the *whole* function. And the second one does not even have defined limits. Infinity is not a number. Hence it's also not any interval. So what essentially you are integrating the whole function in both cases since integrating any function from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is essentially just whole thing put different way. Did I get that right? If not then, I'd much appreciate an answer instead of a comment. Thanks

Comment: Remember that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{-n}^{n}f(x)dx $ so that, if the limit exists, it is a real number whereas $\int f(x)dx$ is still a function.

Comment: @Falcon That's not entirely true. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$ is equal to $\lim_{m,n\to\infty}\int_{-m}^nf(x)dx$. The integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,dx$ does not and should not converge. But it converges according to your definition.

Comment: Yes sorry, it wasn't very clear. I meant that, if the function is integrable on $[-\infty, \infty]$, then its integral equals to $\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{x_k}^{y_k}f(x)dx$ for all $x_k, y_k$ such that $x_k \to -\infty$ and $y_k \to +\infty$.

Comment: Also one more thing: context is important. Arthur's answer below is of course completely correct. However note that occasionally people omit the bounds of integration and take it to  implicitly mean integrate over the whole space. For example, if you see 1.) in an intro calculus setting, then it means the indefinite integral. However, if you see it in a real analysis/measure theory situation it usually means a definite (Lebesgue) integral over the entire domain (usually $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{R}^n$). I personally avoid such lazy notation as much as possible, but just be aware of the context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\int f(x)dx$, without bounds, is taken to mean the antiderivative of $f$. It yields a family of functions, all of which have $f$ as their derivative. It's often called "indefinite integral", and uses integral notation, because of its close connection to (definite) integrals through the fundamental theorem of calculus.

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$, with bounds (finite or infinite, or even just a domain, like so: $\int_{\Bbb R}f(x)dx$), is a (definite) integral, and yields a single number (assuming the integral exists).

Answer (score 3):

I guess that your confusion is coming from some common notation in theoretical physics. They usually drop the infinite bounds of the definite integral. For instance in [expressions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148929/fourier-and-inverse-fourier-transform-in-qft) like:

$$
\tilde{\psi}(k) = \int \psi(x) \, e^{ikx} \ \mathrm{d}x
$$

The integration domain of $(-\infty, \infty)$ is implicit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I will just try to give a counter-example. Let's assume that $\int f(x) dx=\tan^{-1}x + c$ . Then, you can see the difference between the two expressions,$\int f(x)$dx being a family of curves whereas $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx$ is a constant.